# Update db data without losing collapsed rows

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, database

Sorry for being dumb, I'm quite new to PHP.
I have a table filled with data from a database:

machine.php

```
<?php require "database.php"; // here the connection stuff
const DOT_ONLINE = "&#128994;";
const DOT_OFFLINE = "&#128308;";
?>

<table id="tableMachines" class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Online</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Type</th>
        <th scope="col">Address</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM machines ORDER BY address;");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
            $rowId = "row" . $row->name;
            $output = "<tr data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#$rowId'>"
                . "<td>" . ($row->online ? DOT_ONLINE : DOT_OFFLINE) . "</td>"
                . "<td>" . $row->name . "</td>"
                . "<td>" . $row->type . "</td>"
                . "<td>" . $row->address . "</td>"
                ."</tr>";

            echo $output;

            $output = "<tr id='" . $rowId . "' class='collapse fade'>"
                ."<td colspan='4'>"
                ."<table class='table table-borderless'>"
                ."<tr><td>Order: " . $row->job . "</td></tr>"
                ."<tr><td>Length: " . $row->length . "</td></tr>"
                ."</table>"
                ."</td>"
                ."</tr>";

            echo $output;
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>

    </tbody>
</table>

<?php
$db = null;
```

As you can see, the user can click on each row to show some further details.
In the main page I put the above file inside a `div`:

```
<div id="tableMachines">
    <?php require 'machines.php' ?>
</div>
```

Periodically I fetch new data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#tableMachines').load('machines.php');
    }, 5000);
});
```

It works fine, the problem is when the `div` reloads I lose the rows that were shown by the user.

It's true I can keep track of which rows were expanded and manually trigger them again after reloading the PHP code, but I don't think this is the correct approach.

Would you mind to help me to understand how to update the data without interfere with the UI?

Answer (score 1):

If this were me, I would track which last machine ID is pulled through and then send that on your load() call. You can then call `$('#tableMachines').prepend(data)` rather than reloading the whole table - you only reload the latest rows. That way your users choices will be unaffected however you may need to re-bind click/triggers so the new rows expand/hide as well.

Comment: If I understand correctly this would update the details of the machines the user revealed. Instead I need to update the whole table indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Before loading machine.php, you can create a **cookie** named `"expanded_set"` in your jquery code that loads machine.php. Each time visitor toggles, you can populate the cookie. In machine.php file, your cookie will be accessible by `$_COOKIE['user_expandeds']`. Then you can customize machine.php to handle the already-toggled ones to show them also.

I'm not sure of this method for timing issues however, you may also send the `"expanded_set"` to PHP via a `POST` type **form** with a hidden input field with a name which is submitted by jquery automatically also. You can access the posted field with its name as `$_POST['expanded_set']`.

cookie method may fail if cookies are not allowed by the visitor but using a form  method can not be disallowed.

Comment: Got it. I would prefer the POST method as well. So there is no easy solution. Or I have to change approach and use Ajax to update manually each cell...